# UIScrollView Error -EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_i386_BPT, subcode=0x0) error

Tags: ios6

I am implementing some code on iOS and suddenly came across an error as stated above. I am not able to figure out what is the source of the problem. But as per my analysis its due to the UIScrollView.
I am using the ios 6 for development.
Attaching the screen shot of the error.[image]

Here is code that i am using for the development.

```
@interface TutorialDetailViewController ()

@end

@implementation TutorialDetailViewController

@synthesize managedObjectContext;
@synthesize scrollView;
@synthesize imageView;
@synthesize textView;
@synthesize imageTapGestureRecognizer;
@synthesize imagePath;
@synthesize separator;

-(void) dealloc
{
    [managedObjectContext release];
    [scrollView release];
    [imageView release];
    [textView release];
    [imageTapGestureRecognizer release];
    [imagePath release];
    [separator release];
    [super dealloc];
}
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSLog(@"View Did Load - Tutorial Detail View Controller");

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

    PocketScholarAppDelegate *delegateObject = (PocketScholarAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    if(self.managedObjectContext == nil)
    {
        self.managedObjectContext = [delegateObject managedObjectContext];
    }

    //UI Customization

    UIView *backButtonView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 42, 42)] autorelease];

    UIButton *backButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 42, 42)];
    UIImageView *separtorView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(41, 0, 1, 42)];
    separtorView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"NavButtonSeperator.png"];

    [backButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"NavBackIcon.png"]
                          forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [backButton addTarget:self
                   action:@selector(backAction)
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [backButtonView addSubview:backButton];
    [backButtonView addSubview:separtorView];

    [separtorView release];
    [backButton release];

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView: backButtonView];

    //fetch value of the selected tutorial from the user defaults
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSInteger tutorialId = [defaults integerForKey:SELECTED_TUTORIAL];

    NSPredicate *tutorialPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"tut_id==%d",tutorialId];
    NSMutableArray *tutorialArray = [NSObject getDataFromLocalDB:TUTORIAL_ENTITY withPredicate:tutorialPredicate forObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

    Tutorials *tObj = [tutorialArray objectAtIndex:0];

    self.title = tObj.tut_name;

    NSArray *documentDirectoryArray = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentDirectory = [documentDirectoryArray lastObject];

     self.imagePath = [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:tObj.tut_image];

    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

    //Set the content size of the scroll view container
    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(screenRect.size.width, screenRect.size.height);

    self.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(screenRect.size.width/2-70, 20, screenRect.size.width/2-20, screenRect.size.height/2-20)];
    self.imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    self.imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

    self.imageTapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                                         initWithTarget:self
                                                         action:@selector(imageTapped)];
    self.imageTapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    [self.imageView addGestureRecognizer:self.imageTapGestureRecognizer];

    self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:imagePath]];

    if(![tObj.tut_description isEqualToString:@""])
    {
        self.textView = [[UITextView alloc] init];
        [self.textView sizeToFit];
        self.textView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        self.textView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:FONT_NAME size:14.0];
        self.textView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
        self.textView.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:109.0/255.0 green:109.0/255.0 blue:109.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
        self.textView.text = tObj.tut_description;
        self.textView.frame = CGRectMake(20,
                                         self.imageView.frame.size.height+60,
                                         screenRect.size.width-40,
                                         screenRect.size.height);
    }

    self.scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;

    self.separator = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,
                                                                   self.imageView.frame.size.height+40,
                                                                   screenRect.size.width,
                                                                   3)];
    self.separator.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"NavShadow.png"];

    [self.scrollView addSubview:self.imageView];
    [self.scrollView addSubview:separator];
    if(![tObj.tut_description isEqualToString:@""])
    {
        [self.scrollView addSubview:textView];

        CGRect textViewFrame = [textView frame];
        textViewFrame.size.height = self.textView.contentSize.height+40;
        self.textView.frame = textViewFrame;
    }

    CGFloat scrollContentHeight = screenRect.size.height + 80;
    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(screenRect.size.width, scrollContentHeight);

    self.view = self.scrollView;

//    [separator release];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    NSLog(@"Did Receive Memory Warning");
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Custom Methods
-(void) backAction
{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

-(void) imageTapped
{
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:imagePath forKey:SELECTED_IMAGE];
    [defaults synchronize];

    TutorialImageViewController *imageController = [[TutorialImageViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TutorialImageViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:imageController animated:YES];
    [imageController release];

}

@end
```

Comment: This is sorted out. Was the problem with the IBOUTLET.

Comment: How did you end up fixing this.  I think I've got the same problem.  I have a view with a scroll view that is an IBOutlet and when I try to return to the view I get the EXC_BREAKPOINT error.  If I remove the outlet, everything works fine, though my view is messed up.

Comment: Just remove all the Outlets and set the values again in XIB files.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that, but it didn't work.  I did, however, find that putting the calling scrollView.contentSize in viewWillAppear or viewDidLoad is causing the problem.  It seems to be removing the outlet for some reason.  Placing the contentSize call inside of viewDidAppear seems to fix the problem.