# How to add a callout having one title

Tags: iphone, ios, mkmapview, cllocationmanager

My map code:

```
if (latitude != [NSNull null] && longitude != [NSNull null])
    {
    location.latitude=[latitude doubleValue];
    location.longitude=[longitude doubleValue];
    MyAnnotationView *newannotation=[[MyAnnotationView alloc]initWithTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Bus-%d",h] latitude:location.latitude longitude:location.longitude];
    [self.myMap addAnnotation:newannotation];
    myMap.mapType=MKMapTypeStandard;
    [myMap setCenterCoordinate:location animated:YES];
    MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(location,1000,1000);
    [myMap setRegion:region animated:YES];

    }

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{

location.latitude=newLocation.coordinate.latitude;
location.longitude=newLocation.coordinate.longitude;
MyAnnotationView *newannotation=[[MyAnnotationView alloc]initWithTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Bus-%d",h] latitude:location.latitude longitude:location.longitude];
[self.myMap addAnnotation:newannotation];
MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(location,1000, 1000);
[myMap setRegion:region animated:YES];
[myMap setCenterCoordinate:newLocation.coordinate animated:YES];
}
```

**mkannotationview.h**

```
@implementation MyAnnotationView
@synthesize title,coordinate;
-(id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)newTitle latitude:(float)newLatitude longitude:(float)newLongitude
{

    if (self=[super init])

    {
        title=newTitle;
        coordinate.latitude=newLatitude;
        coordinate.longitude=newLongitude;

    }
    return  self;
}
```

How can I add a callout with that title? It's not popping out when I click on that annotation. When I click, I get the following thread error

```
EXC_BREAKPOINT(code=EXC_1386+BPT,subcode 0.0)
```

Comment: someone help me....am stuck with this

Comment: This error might have been caused by something else than your map annotation. Check this questions and answers:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14184435/uiscrollview-error-exc-breakpoint-code-exc-i386-bpt-subcode-0x0-error
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14184435/uiscrollview-error-exc-breakpoint-code-exc-i386-bpt-subcode-0x0-error

Comment: Does the project use ARC?  Is the `title` property declared as `@property (copy) NSString *title;`?

Comment: no it doesnot use ARC.@anna.when i click on the map it shows this error...

Comment: Since it doesn't use ARC, try doing `title = [newTitle copy];` in the `init` method.